# Is the at-sign in Instagram handles pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, contemporary-english

I realize that this question is likely factually unanswerable, but I am curious about opinions and argument for either option.

Say I want to write at the end of an article that I want my reader to follow me on Instagram. I could write:

> Please follow me on Instagram at @gregorsamsa

implying that the `@` is silent. I could also opt to give the `@` sign more respect and write instead:

> Please follow me on Instagram @gregorsamsa

Of course, in e-mail addresses the `@` is pronounced, but I feel resistance to the pronunciation of the `@` in the Instagram handle. Is this justified or is it a sign of me losing grip on my youth?

Comment: It only matters when you are relaying the address vocally (when you must pronounce it), or subvocalizing as you read, in which case, it's up to you.

Comment: You could equally well say "Call me on 0171111111" or "Call me 0171111111" (although you might prefer a comma in the latter).

Comment: @Stuart F That is reminiscent of the surreal old joke _"Call me a taxi!" ... _"You're a taxi."

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty I'm trying to think of the term for the no-outward-sign-at-all type of reading.